# php tidy moving script tags to head

Tags: tidy

I'm trying to run html tidy with `show-body-only` as `true`, and it's moving inline script tags into the `<head>`, so it effectively removes all scripts. Here's my process:

```
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($str, array('show-body-only'=>true));
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
```

where `$str` is:

```
<div id="main">
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
</div>
```

This outputs:

`<div id="main"></div>`

If I turn off 'show-body-only', you'll see that the script is in the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="foo.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
</script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="main"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How would I prevent tidy from moving script tags when I do `show-body-only`?

Comment: This issue affects `pytidylib` and `tidylib` in general. Would love a solution.